# All the values of x that satisfy $F(x) + F(2a) = 0$ are:

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

For a quadratic function F(x) = $$\int_0^x f(t)dt$$

Assume that a is a positive number and the function $F(x)$ has extreme values at $x = -2a,2a.$

All the values of x that satisfy $F(x) + F(2a) = 0$ are:

The answer is $-2a$ and $4a$.

I completely understand how $-2a=x$ works. We have a minimum at $2a$ and a maximum at $-2a$, so they logically balance each other out. If you run the math, they equal zero when added.

However, how on earth could $4a=x$, when it is just $2(2a)$ be an  opposite of $2a$?

The only thing I could really even think of was maybe the graph is curving to where at $2a$ we have a minimum, at $-2a$ we have a maximum, and at $4a$ we have another maximum that is the exact same distance away from the origin as $2a$ is, but I have no idea how I would even begin to test that.

All help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: You call the function "quadratic"... what do you mean by this? Is it a quadratic polynomial? In that case, how can a quadratic polynomial have two extreme values, when they famously have only one: the vertex? Or is there some other meaning of "quadratic" that I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe $f$ is meant to be quadratic instead of $F$.

Comment: I wrote it exactly as it is written in the question. @Theo Bendit
F(x) equals that integral where f(t) is the integrand.

Comment: @TizzleRizzle: The only quadratic $F$ that can possibly meet the requirements of $F'(-2a) = F'(2a) = 0$ and $F(0) = 0$ is the zero polynomial.  There must be some mistake in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the intent is that $f$ is a quadratic, making $F$ a cubic.

$$F(x) = \alpha x^3 + \beta x^2 + \gamma x + \delta$$
$$F'(x) = f(x) = 3\alpha x^2 + 2\beta x + \gamma$$

$F(0)$ is the integral of a finite function on a zero-length interval, thus $F(0) = 0$, so $\delta = 0$.

For $F(x)$ to have extreme values at $x = \pm 2a$ means that $F'(\pm 2a) = f(\pm 2a) = 0$.  Thus, $f$ is a multiple of $(x + 2a)(x - 2a) = x^2 - 4a^2$.  Multiply by $3\alpha$ to make the $x^2$ coefficient match up.

$$f(x) = 3\alpha x^2 - 12a^2\alpha$$
$$\beta = 0$$
$$\gamma = -12a^2 \alpha$$

$$F(x) = \alpha x^3 - 12a^2 \alpha x = \alpha(x^3 - 12a^2x)$$
$$F(2a) = \alpha((2a)^3 - 12a^2(2a)) = \alpha(8-24)a^3 = -16\alpha a^3$$

Having obtained a formula for $F$ (to within a multiplicative constant), we can now solve the title equation:

$$F(x) + F(2a) = 0$$
$$\alpha(x^3 - 12a^2x) -16\alpha a^3 = 0$$
$$x^3 - 12a^2x - 16 a^3 = 0$$

Assume that $x = au$.  Then:

$$(au)^3 - 12a^2(au) - 16 a^3 = 0$$
$$a^3u^3 - 12a^3u - 16a^3 = 0$$
$$a^3(u^3 - 12u - 16) = 0$$

We are given that $a > 0$, so we must have $u^3 - 12u - 16$.  By the Rational Root Theorem, $u$ must be a factor of 16.  Through trial and error, we can find that $u = -2$ and $u = 4$ are solutions.  Fully factoring the cubic gives:

$$(u + 2)^2(u - 4) = 0$$

So the third root is just a duplicate of $u = -2$.  So we have $u \in \lbrace -2, 4 \rbrace$.

IOW, $x \in \lbrace -2a, 4a \rbrace$, Q.E.D.